# How can I have my terminal start with an ASCII banner?

Tags: command-line, ascii

How can I have my terminal in Ubuntu start with an ASCII banner every time from default?

Answer (score 11):

Your .bashrc file is executed every time you open a new terminal, so if you add this line to it:

```
echo "____ENTER_ASCII_ART_HERE_____"
```

That should do it

Answer (score 10):

You could use `cowsay` to show a particular message coming from one of its ascii animals; there are elephants, ducks, dragons, and many more humorous examples.

```
sudo apt-get install cowsay
```

List the animals with `cowsay -l` and then at the **top** of your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_aliases`, place, for example, the 'eyes' object:

```
cowsay -f eyes "Welcome $USER"
```

You could take advantage of shell variables like `$USER` or `$SHELL`, etc, and have them printed to the command line. For how to add the timestamp, see this [related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/193416/adding-timestamps-to-terminal-prompts/193815#193815).

[image]

Answer (score 9):

The is a command called `banner` that will print a banner of ascii art. Install by running

```
sudo apt-get install sysvbanner
```

And place a line in your `.bashrc` file so that it will run every time you start your terminal:

```
banner EXAMPLE BANNER
```

And it will print

```
####### #     #    #    #     # ######  #       #######
#        #   #    # #   ##   ## #     # #       #
#         # #    #   #  # # # # #     # #       #
#####      #    #     # #  #  # ######  #       #####
#         # #   ####### #     # #       #       #
#        #   #  #     # #     # #       #       #
####### #     # #     # #     # #       ####### #######

######     #    #     # #     # ####### ######
#     #   # #   ##    # ##    # #       #     #
#     #  #   #  # #   # # #   # #       #     #
######  #     # #  #  # #  #  # #####   ######
#     # ####### #   # # #   # # #       #   #
#     # #     # #    ## #    ## #       #    #
######  #     # #     # #     # ####### #     #
```