# How to show ASCII art at the top of the terminal when it's opened?

Tags: command-line, customization, ascii-art

As you can see on this screenshot of [Mik](https://askubuntu.com/users/76204/mik)'s Guake he has a startup message of ASCII art when he opens it, and that's what I'd like to do, can someone help me?

[image: Mik's Guake]

Comment: Please see [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/223836/how-can-i-have-the-terminal-starting-with-ascii-banner), where I explain one way of doing it. Unfortunately, your question is a possible duplicate of that one.

Comment: @Mik I think my question is a "real" duplicate of this one. Anyway, could you please explain me how to make the text get colored? Is that a argument on `echo`?

Comment: The prompt is red because I have specified some ANSI escape codes in the PS1 line in my `.bash_aliases` ; you can do this manually in your `bash_aliases` or `.bashrc` for various things. You should also be able to use the preferences in `gnome-terminal` or `guake` to alter some of the appearance settings. There's some good answers on this site discussing the use of colour and ANSI escape codes in the terminal.

Comment: Congrats. Your question almost has 100k views!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Open your terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type as

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

There type as

`echo " Hi Zignd"` then close and save it.

then type this command to reload bashrc .

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

You will what you want.

for example :I made my self.

[image]

Comment: Make sure that this `echo` is within a condition that checks that the output is a tty, or (your choice) the shell is interactive. Otherwise you'll break scp, rsync.

Comment: You can also add [`screenfetch`](https://askubuntu.com/a/989759/349837).

Comment: The `source` command is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 19):

To extend @snow's answer, put the code below from the very first line of your `.bashrc`. And be proud to be ubuntu user :)

```
echo "MMMMMMMMMMMMKlxMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMW0occlxNM"
echo "MMMMMMMMMMMMOcxMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMKOXMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNdcoxkOlc0"
echo "MMMMMMMMMMMMOcxMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMdcOMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMkoO0lckkcl"
echo "dxWMMMM0d0MMOcoxdooxONMMMOdXMMMMXdkMMWkxdoodxONMMMdcldddkMXdxWMMMM0dKM0coOxk0xcd"
echo "ccNMMMMxckMMOco0XNXkclKMMxc0MMMMKcoMMNllKXXXkclXMMdcxKKKXMKclNMMMMkc0MM0oclldokN"
echo "ccNMMMMxckMMOcxMMMMMOclWMxc0MMMMKcoMMNllWMMMMdcOMMdcOMMMMMKclNMMMMkc0MMMMNXXNWMM"
echo "ccNMMMMxckMMOcxMMMMMKccNMxc0MMMMKcoMMNllWMMMMxckMMdcOMMMMMKclNMMMMkc0MMMMMMMMMMM"
echo "lcKMMMMxckMMOcxMMMMWdcxMMkcxMMMMKcoMMNllWMMMMkckMMxckMMMMMNccKMMMMkc0MMMMMMMMMMM"
echo "0lcxkkklckMMOclkOkxlckWMMNocdkkkdcoMMNllWMMMMkckMMXlcxkkxNM0lcxkkkoc0MMMMMMMMMMM"
echo "MNxlccloxXMMXxolccokNMMMMMWOolclox0MMWxkWMMMM0d0MMMXxlclxNMMNklcclokXMMMMMMMMMMM"
```

OR

```
echo "       _                 _         "
echo " _   _| |__  _   _ _ __ | |_ _   _ "
echo "| | | | '_ \| | | | '_ \| __| | | |"
echo "| |_| | |_) | |_| | | | | |_| |_| |"
echo " \__,_|_.__/ \__,_|_| |_|\__|\__,_|"
```

The secret to these image like characters is to use an image converter to ASCII characters. There are lots of free tools in the wild like `toilet` or `figlet` but I personally use `jp2a`.

You can also use [this](http://ascii.mastervb.net/) site for generating text to ASCII instead of image to ASCII.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the site to generate ascii images

Comment: +1 for jp2a (why use a website?)

Comment: Make sure that these `echo`s are within a condition that checks that the output is a tty, or (your choice) the shell is interactive. Otherwise you'll break scp, rsync.

Answer (score 10):

How do we apply ASCII art into the terminal?

There are numerous ways of generating ASCII art, including specialized software and manual building but there are also websites that generate ASCII art by simply entering the desired name.

First we need to generate/create the ASCII "code": visit this [website](http://patorjk.com/software/taag/#p=display&f=Graffiti&t=Type%20Something%20), type the desired name and copy the "live" generated ASCII result.

Then create a text file named art and paste into it the above mentioned generated ASCII result, copy the art file in your home folder (navigate here by clicking Nautilus sidebar's Home),
open the `.bashrc` file (to make it viewable, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) and paste on the bottom of the page

**cat art**

[image]
**Worth mentioning:**

The above-mentioned site contains hundreds of different fonts for generating ASCII that feature various sizes, 3D-look, etc.

[image]

[**Source**](http://www.iloveubuntu.net/fancify-your-gnome-terminal-ascii-art)

As for images to ASCII go to this [website](http://www.glassgiant.com/ascii/)

Answer (score 7):

First generate a ascii drawing. I recommend `asciio`:

```
apt-get install asciio
```

[image: asciio]

Example:

```
  .-------.
  |  Hi   |
  '-------'
      ^      (\_/)
      '----- (O.o)
             (> <)
```

Copy and paste the drawing in file:

```
vim /home/<youruser>/banner
```

Finally, add at the end of file to read when you open a new bash:

```
echo "cat banner" >> /home/<youruser>/.bashrc
```

Open another terminal:

[image: ready]

Comment: Can you please translate your answer to English?

Comment: Sorry. I tried.

Comment: I haven't permission for post images yet. Sorry.

Comment: That's fine, I am aware of that.

Answer (score 5):

This one takes a png image file and outputs a facsimile onto your terminal

If you [have nodejs installed](https://nodejs.org/en/)  then issue

```
npm install -g picture-tube
```

then put this into bottom of your ~/.bashrc

```
echo "picture-tube  --cols 60   /some/path/myimage.png"
      picture-tube  --cols 60   /some/path/myimage.png
```

code is at  https://github.com/substack/picture-tube

[image]

enjoy

Answer (score 5):

[image]

```
sudo apt-get install figlet

echo "Hello world!" | figlet | color_it.sh 54
```

cat color_it.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash 

## A.M.Danischewski 2015+(c) Free - for (all (uses and 
## modifications)) - except you must keep this notice intact. 

declare INPUT_TXT=""
declare    ADD_LF="\n" 
declare -i DONE=0
declare -r COLOR_NUMBER="${1:-247}"
declare -r ASCII_FG="\\033[38;05;"
declare -r COLOR_OUT="${ASCII_FG}${COLOR_NUMBER}m"

function show_colors() { 
   ## perhaps will add bg 48 to first loop eventually 
 for fgbg in 38; do for color in {0..256} ; do 
 echo -en "\\033[${fgbg};5;${color}m ${color}\t\\033[0m"; 
 (($((${color}+1))%10==0)) && echo; done; echo; done
} 

if [[ ! $# -eq 1 || ${1} =~ ^-. ]]; then 
  show_colors 
  echo " Usage: ${0##*/} <color fg>" 
  echo "  E.g. echo \"Hello world!\" | figlet | ${0##*/} 54" 
else  
 while IFS= read -r PIPED_INPUT || { DONE=1; ADD_LF=""; }; do 
  PIPED_INPUT=$(sed 's#\\#\\\\#g' <<< "${PIPED_INPUT}")
  INPUT_TXT="${INPUT_TXT}${PIPED_INPUT}${ADD_LF}"
  ((${DONE})) && break; 
 done
 echo -en "${COLOR_OUT}${INPUT_TXT}\\033[00m"
fi
```

its typical to create a dir ~/bin and make all those files visible

```
mkdir ~/bin
# ... put above color_it.sh as file ~/bin/color_it.sh
chmod +x ~/bin/color_it.sh   # make it executable
export PATH=${HOME}/bin:${PATH}  # add this line to your ~/.bashrc

echo "Hello world!" | figlet | color_it.sh 34
```

Answer (score 4):

You can add interesting ASCII arts on your terminal without leaving your terminal. `cowsay` has some of the coolest ASCII arts and piping `fortune` outputs into cowsay can take this to another level. Let's see how this is done, open your terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install cowsay
```

Now cowsay is installed let's have some fun, add the following command

```
cowsay I am in a good mooooo-d.
```

If you don't like the cow, there is a mystical zoo within your terminal, type

```
cowsay -f dragon Who dared to wake me up?
```

To bring up a list of all the animals in your mystical zoo type `cowsay -l`.
If you prefer 'thinking animal' over talking one try

```
cowthink -f <animal name> <your message>
```

`< >` are to be ignored. If you want to display a same custom message each time you log in please continue, otherwise skip to the next step.

> Copy your ASCII art and go to the home directory. Create a file
>   `<newfile.txt>`, paste your ASCII art inside the file, and save it.
>   Open a file`.bashrc` from the home directory. Add the following on the bottom 
>   line of the file and save it.
>
> `cat <newfile.txt>`
>
> You are done :) reopen your terminal.

---

Let's make your animal a little more intelligent by adding `fortune`

```
sudo apt-get install fortune
```

Go to the home directory and open `.bashrc` and add the following as top line of the file

```
fortune | cowsay -f <your animal>
```

Now save the file and you are done :)

Answer (score 3):

Run these commands as `root`

1. Install figlet

   `apt-get install figlet`
2. For editing .bashrc file, we need a text editor, here we use leafpad

   `apt-get install leafpad`
3. Edit the .bashrc file located in the root folder.

   `leafpad /root/.bashrc`
4. Scroll down to the end of the file then type figlet your name

   `figlet Anonymous`
5. Type in the next line echo "your message"

   `echo "We are Anonymous"`
6. Save the file (File->Save)

[image: img_terminal]

Finally, relaunch your terminal again with the `root` privileges

Comment: it is not working for non-root terminal, 2nd i like your terminal tree orientation is there any link for that i can refer

Answer (score 0):

#### Show the colorful TEXT ART in Linux Terminal

[image: ascii_text_art]

Follow these steps:

1. Install `figlet` and `lolcat`:

   ```
   sudo apt install figlet lolcat
   ```
2. Install `git`:

   ```
   sudo apt install git
   ```
3. Download some figlet fonts from GitHub:

   ```
   cd Desktop
   git clone https://github.com/xero/figlet-fonts.git
   ```

   or visit the link: https://github.com/xero/figlet-fonts.git
4. Copy all the font files from `figlet-fonts` directory to `/usr/share/figlet/`:

   ```
   sudo cp figlet-fonts/* /usr/share/figlet/
   ```
5. For editing the `.bashrc` file, we need a text editor. Here we use `nano`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install nano
   ```
6. Open the `.bashrc` file (located in the `root` folder) in the `nano` editor:

   ```
   sudo nano /root/.bashrc
   ```
7. Scroll down to the end of the file (press the down arrow key) and then type the following:

   ```
   figlet -f font_name your_text | lolcat
   ```

   For example:

   ```
   figlet -f 3d Hello World! | lolcat
   ```
8. To save the file press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit.
9. Now launch your terminal with admin privilegesand you will see the text art. :)

Note: The text art color will automatically change each time you launch the terminal (with admin privileges).

Answer (score 0):

Here's my terminal slash screen:

[image: Terminal Splash Screen]

It combines elements of other answers here including `figlet` and `toilet` depending on which is already installed on your system. The full setup (bash script) is explained here:

- [Terminal splash screen with Weather, Calendar, Time & Sysinfo?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1020692/terminal-splash-screen-with-weather-calendar-time-sysinfo/1020693#1020693)