# How to get Ascii Ubuntu logo in terminal

Tags: command-line

I was on some linux forum the other day on my phone and people where screen dumping  using terminal and everyone had ascii art of their computers they typed something like "screenfetch" or something I don't remember.

Comment: https://fossbytes.com/linux-distribution-logo-ascii-art-terminal/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Archey is a script that displays system info in the terminal with a logo of this the Linux distro in ASCII art.

**Install Archey in ubuntu**

```
sudo apt-get install lsb-release scrot
wget http://github.com/downloads/djmelik/archey/archey-0.2.8.deb
sudo dpkg -i archey-0.2.8.deb
```

**Using Archey**

run the command

```
archey
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

There is `screenfetch` - It has information about the theme you are using, as well as screen resolution.

1. Download the code from:  http://git.silverirc.com/cgit.cgi/screenfetch.git/plain/screenfetch-dev
2. Copy the code and Paste the code in a new file in gedit and save as `screenfetch` in your Home Folder.
3. Run

   ```
   chmod +x screenfetch
   ```

   (making sure your terminal is directed to your home folder)
4. Then:

   ```
   ./screenfetch
   ```

Here are details about the program https://github.com/KittyKatt/screenFetch

[image]

---

This also has the option of auto taking a screenshot - if you have `scrot` installed.

1. Install scrot:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install scrot
   ```
2. Run screenfecth with -s

   ```
   ./screenfetch -s
   ```

[image]

Comment: how did you get your name to display in 3d above screenfetch?

Comment: @Skateguy http://askubuntu.com/questions/234678/how-to-show-ascii-art-at-the-top-of-the-terminal-when-its-opened

Comment: Hey hi! How did you get that Mateo written in that format?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/234678/how-to-show-ascii-art-at-the-top-of-the-terminal-when-its-opened

Answer (score 9):

A simple one is neofetch. It also displays ascii ubuntu some other info.
install with

```
sudo apt install neofetch
```

Comment: `Unable to locate package neofetch`

Comment: it's there on 22.04

Answer (score 5):

### [`screenfetch`](https://github.com/KittyKatt/screenFetch)

On more recent versions of Ubuntu (>16.04), you can install screenfetch [from official repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/xenial/screenfetch):

```
apt install screenfetch
```

[image]

- Official code is [on GitHub](https://github.com/KittyKatt/screenFetch).
- [PPA also available](https://launchpad.net/%7Edjcj/+archive/ubuntu/screenfetch)

Comment: What about the last line (RAM Info) ? Does this mean 7814 MiB is used of the total 11915 MiB OR that much is left ??

Comment: RAM: Used / Total