# Streaming music like a radio show

Tags: music, streaming

I'd like to be able to stream music, realtime, to a friend. Not in my LAN, but over the internet. I've done a lot of research on how to do this, one option was setting up a shoutcast server, but that isn't realtime as far as I know. VLC allows streaming, but again, this is not realtime.

I can't imagine this being so hard to do. I did a lot of research, and the "best" solution I could find was to use teamspeak with a music player plugin. It would be soo much more convenient though if I could just open rythmbox and start a stream, in which someone else could join and listen.

Comment: I've streamed over LAN with VLC, which isn't realtime; it has 20 seconds latency or so

Comment: You can try with Icecast: http://askubuntu.com/questions/28496/how-do-i-setup-an-icecast-server-for-broadcasting-audio-in-my-network. However some latency is inherent to network streams due to buffering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Music Player Daemon](http://www.musicpd.org/) or short `MPD` is an excellent choice for streaming audio to other computers or even mobile devices, like phones/mp3-players, that are connected with the net.

> MPD is designed around a client/server architecture, where the clients and server (MPD is the server) interact over a network. Thus, running MPD is only half of the equation. To use MPD, you need to install a MPD client (aka MPD interface).
>   Command-line Clients

**You can choose between a terminal or graphical based interface
clients**:

- [mpc](http://www.musicpd.org/clients/mpc/) - a solid, lightweight, simple mpd client, written in C.
  Console Clients
- [ncmpc](http://www.musicpd.org/clients/ncmpc/) - A curses client written in C.
- [ncmpcpp](http://mpd.wikia.com/wiki/Client%3aNcmpcpp) - A curses client written in C++ tailored after ncmpc.
  Graphical Clients
- [gmpc](http://gmpclient.org/) (Gnome Music Player Client) - A fully featured client.
- [ario](http://ario-player.sourceforge.net/) - Another GTK based client.
- More clients can be found on the [Wiki](http://mpd.wikia.com/wiki/Clients)

---

[Ubuntu Install](http://mpd.wikia.com/wiki/Install) Procedure:

1. First, edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` and enable the `'universe'` repository. After you make this change, you will have to run `apt-get update`.
   You can use Synaptic. If for some reason this installation fails, this [howto](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=5194) on the Ubuntu Forums may help, or the [user-manual](http://www.musicpd.org/doc/user/).

> ```
> sudo apt-get update        
> sudo apt-get install mpd
> ```

OR

1. If you just need only MP3 and FLAC support through ALSA, then you can compile it from source:

> ```
> download the latest sources  
> extract them to some directory (for example 'mpd-x-x-x')  
> go to this directory (for example 'cd mpd-x-x-x')  
> install the dependencies, compile and install:
> ```

```
 sudo apt-get update   
 sudo apt-get install libasound2-dev libmad0-dev libid3tag0-dev libflac-dev libflac++-dev libglib2.0-dev

./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: ..and does this require port-forwarding?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about the subject but if you want to use rhythmbox, perhaps this might be interesting:
[rhythmbox-ampache](https://code.google.com/p/rhythmbox-ampache/) and [ampache](https://github.com/ampache/ampache/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MPD` .It has capability to steam music.

If you want to stream audio from mpd to another computer , edit `/etc/mpd.conf` on the server running mpd to use  the IP address of the target computer and `/etc/pulse/default.pa` or `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/default.pa`(typically `~/.config/pulse/default.pa`) on the target computer using the IP address of the server.

For more  see here. [wiki.archlinux.org](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mpd)