# Display running clock in terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-terminal

I want to display running clock inside terminal.

I have already gone through [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360063/how-to-show-a-running-clock-in-terminal-before-the-command-prompt) answer but this method only works in zsh terminal. But I want to display in bash.

Is there any other way to display it in bash terminal?